# Android TextPaint's FontMetrics Changes with same TextSize

Tags: android, text, size

I have a custom TextView that reads textSize value from xml and render the text accordingly. In fact my TextView works just fine, until I got the requirement to change the text size dynamically with seekbar, I ran into a problem:

I set default textSize=24sp in my xml, it works fine.
But if I programmatically change the text size and re-layout the text, the line width is no longer the same even if I set the text size to the same value 24sp.

So I printed a log in the function where I set the text size to print those font specs:

```
E/MyTextView: font_size: 48.0 top: -51 bottom: 14 line_width: 65
E/MyTextView: font_size: 40.0 top: -34 bottom: 10 line_width: 44
E/MyTextView: font_size: 48.0 top: -40 bottom: 12 line_width: 52
```

**here**, line 1 is the text size being read from xml and set via `setTextSize` function, line 3 is the text size read from dimensions and set via the same `setTextSize` function.

As we can see, even with the same font_size set to the textPaint, the `top` and `bottom` comes in different value.

If there's anything I'm doing wrong?

Edit:(codes)

```
public MyLayout(MyTextView host, int height, String text, float textSize) {
        ...
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        mTextPaint.setSubpixelText(true);
        setLineSpecs();
        ....
    }

private void setLineSpecs() {
        fmi = mTextPaint.getFontMetricsInt();
        mLineWidth = Math.abs(fmi.top) + Math.abs(fmi.bottom);
        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "MyTextView", "font_size: " + mTextPaint.getTextSize() + " top: " + fmi.top + " bottom: " + fmi.bottom + " line_width: " + mLineWidth);
    }
```

**my `setTextSiez(float size)` function**:

```
public void setTextSize(float size) {
        if (mTextPaint.getTextSize() != size) {
            mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);
            setLineSpecs();
        }
        layoutText(mHeight);
    }
```

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink now have a look